# Show MS Excel Syntax as you type Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have Office 2013 on my work computer and Office 2016 on my personal computer. On my work computer in Excel 2013 when you type a formula you get the suggested syntax for formulas as you type, but on my personal computer I am not getting this. On my work computer, for example, if I type the SUM formula I will see the suggestion:

`SUM(number1, [number2], ...)`

but I won't get this syntax suggestion for my personal computer (all I get is `SUM`)

Is this just the version of Excel that I have on the different computers or is there a setting that I can turn on to show syntax suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't have Excel 2016 to test, but it seems the term for those are ScreenTips/ToolTips. Here's instructions on turning them *off* in older Excels; perhaps try doing the reverse? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/289146

Comment: Thank you so much @Etheur! The setting can be found under File>Options>Advanced then in the Display section, I checked 'Show Function ScreenTips'

Answer (score 0):

Start writing a formula, e.g. =vloo, then click `ALT + DOWN ARROW`. This enables/disables it for me.